# Hide Element If It the Last Item in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I need to hide `TimelineConnector` if it is on the last item. How will i be able to hide it?
Pls check my codesandbox

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-fermi-pjhsk?file=/demo.js)

```
 {timelines.lastIndexOf(index) !== 1 ? <TimelineConnector /> : ""}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
{index < (timelines.length - 1) && <TimelineConnector />}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do using ternary operator

```
{timelines.map((timeline, index) =>
  index !== timelines.length - 1 ? (
    <TimelineItem>
       ...
    </TimelineItem>
  ) : null
)}
```

Forked demo

[image: Edit vigorous-wave-zi6xq]

Answer (score 1):

Just compare to `timelines` length:

```
{index !== timelines.length - 1 && <TimelineConnector />}
```

Comment: Thank you it works too but the other user answered first. But I upvoted you

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
{timelines.length !== (index - 1) ? <TimelineConnector /> : null}
```

Comment: I guess there is a mistake in your condition

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a check of `length` with `index - 1`

`{index - 1 != timelines.length ? <TimelineConnector /> : ""}`

[Forked demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-night-exoqp?file=/demo.js:1553-1613)